# Can you set the selected payment option in admin?

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

I'm trying to change the selected payment option in the checkout and noticed its being checked with this:

```
<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm presuming `getSelectedMethodCode` is coming from the admin somewhere? If so does anyone know where it's being set please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto methods.phtml at `app/design/frontent/yourpackage/your template/template/checkout/onepage/payment/`

AND find

```
<input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio" /></span>
        <?php $oneMethod = $_code; ?>
```

and here you need put your logic.

```
<?php if($_code=='yourpayemntcode'): ?> checked="checked"   <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks but can you choose which payment option is to be pre-selected in admin? Or is this not possible?

Comment: You can Make Module For that , make admin select the default gateway there and fetch the value on above template and put it in the logic , there is no stock functionality for that, accept the answer as well if you found it useful